# Split rows by null value - Talend Data Integration

Tags: talend

I need to split a column of a file into multiple outputs.

[image]

I am working with talent data integration.

Thanks!

I need to split the row into multiples outputs, the row must be divided up to the null value.

1 Output

[image]

2 Output

[image]

Comment: So you mean you want to split a file by the blank line, is that correct? I’d do, can you provide the text rather than an image? Edit your question and include that. Also, what format is the file?

Comment: Thats right, just split the column by null value

Comment: You didn’t answer my other questions.